# following another user's symlink

Tags: linux, shell, permissions, symbolic-link

How does one traverse a symlink owned by another user?

On my ubuntu box, I have a symlink:

```
root@anonymous:/var/tmp# ls -l
total 24
lrwxrwxrwx 1 lab  lab    26 Dec 15 18:27 blank.zip -> /home/admin/important6.zip
```

Accessing it as root gives:

```
root@anonymous:/var/tmp# more blank.zip 
blank.zip: Permission denied
```

If I change ownership to root, though:

```
root@anonymous:/var/tmp# chown -h root:root blank.zip ; more blank.zip 
PK...
```

Comment: I should point out that /var/tmp does not have sticky bits set.

Comment: More data:  this appears to be a problem only in /var/tmp and /tmp but not in another directory (say ~root).  That suggests that this is some sort of kernel-level access control check ... but I don't seem to have either selinux or apparmor running.

Answer (score 2):

`chown -h` changes the ownership of `/home/admin/important6.zip` not of `blank.zip`.  You already have full access to the `blank.zip` symlink as root.

If you look at the permissions of important6.zip you'll no doubt see why it doesn't work.

Comment: I think the opposite ... chown -h does *not* dereference the link.  I'm doing this as root ... I have access to read important6.zip.

Comment: I think you are right, and I misread the man page :)

Answer (score 2):

This happens because of the `fs.protected_symlinks` feature. Since `/var/tmp` is a public directory (world-writable and with the 'sticky' bit), there is a risk that someone could create a symlink to e.g. `/etc/passwd` and trick a system service into writing custom data to it. To avoid this, symlinks located in a 'sticky' directory are followed only when their owner matches.

See the following articles for more information:

- https://git.kernel.org/linus/800179c9b8a1e796e441674776d11cd4c05d61d7
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/Roadmap/KernelHardening#Symlink_Protection

Comment: "Someone could create a symlink to e.g. `/etc/passwd` and trick a system service into writing custom data to it". I think it is called *[confused deputy problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confused_deputy_problem)*.

Comment: The problem is that, as I mention in my comment on the original problem, /var/tmp/ does *not* have the sticky bit set.

Comment: You sure? It does have that on nearly every Linux system out there. (And if it doesn't, it _should_...)

Comment: Yes ... I unstuck it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not about the ownsership of the symlink but the ownership of the `/home/admin` directory. Since user lab does not have the permission to view another users home directory (unless otherwise chmod’ed), the symlink cannot follow.

Since root can view anoyone’s home directory, the change of ownership to root solves the problem in your case.

You may add lab to the group of admin and chmod `/home/admin` to `770` (or `740` for just allowing read to the group members). Usually home directories are chmod’ed `700`. It is not recommended to increase the permission to all others (last 3 bits) for security purposes.

Comment: Why does the ownership of admin matter?  I'm doing this all as root.

Comment: Well I'm stuck :) I changed the ownership of the symlink to a non-sudoer user and even chmod'ed the linked file to 0, but root still accesses.

Comment: It may be because of a SELinux or fuse related issue.

Comment: You may check: http://serverfault.com/questions/12162/directory-that-a-user-can-read-but-root-cant https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/41452/apache-not-following-symlink-in-varwwwhtml/